# Specific activerecord attributes becomes translation missing on production with Rails i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

My default locale is `:ja`, and I have this for `user.ja.yml`:

```
ja:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: プロフィール
    attributes:
      user:
        account_id: アカウントID
        birth_day: 生年月日
        email: メールアドレス
    errors:
      user:
        invalid_zip_code: 郵便番号に該当する住所がみつかりません。  
  enumerize:
    user:
      sex:
        man: 男性
        woman: 女性
```

My application raises a translation missing error on a specific model on the production server. It works fine on other models and on development and local production environments.

On local production environment:

```
I18n.t('activerecord.attributes.user.account_id')
# => "アカウントID"
```

On production server:

```
I18n.t('activerecord.attributes.user.account_id')
# => "translation missing: ja.activerecord.attributes.user.account_id"
```

`activerecord.model` does not raise an error:

```
I18n.t('activerecord.models.user')
# => "プロフィール"
```

Comment: Sure it won't work because you should specify the key which has string and `user` has other keys (not string) so you can try with `I18n.t('activerecord.attributes.user.account_id')` on production.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MoamenNaanou I mean production server can't read entire tree on 'activerecord.attributes.user'. It returns child tree by hash if works fine. I've edited question and `I18n.t('activerecord.attributes.user.account_id') => translation missing: ja.activerecord.attributes.user.account_id`

Comment: @sawa I've edited question. The problem is that only the production server raises translation missing on specific translation file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.
There was a locale file which has no content on attributes.

```
ja:
  activerecord:
    models:
      authentication: SNS連携
    attributes:
```

This file affects other files.